# SQLite spacing error

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm creating a SQLite. I added all the first fourth columns, but when adding the fifth column called "productadd". It cannot be found. What's wrong with this following code?

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists producttable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + " productidno"
                + " TEXT ,"
                + " productname"
                + " TEXT,"
                + " productprice" 
                + " TEXT,"
                + " productdest" 
                + " TEXT,"
                + " productadd"
                +" TEXT)");
```

Comment: try deleting pervious one first

Comment: Try to add a semi colon to end your string, the last line would be +" TEXT);");

Comment: @blaffie I tried but no help.

Comment: As @Stacks28 suggests, delete the old table (`drop table producttable`) (or database file) first. It's possible you're trying to create the table when it already exists; in your case the `if not exists` key ensures no error, however nothing will be created in this case either.

Comment: @mah I get it and have solved the prob. Thanks!

Comment: @EtAndrea i think u must delete db from ddms -> ur package->try delete ur db from there

Comment: ^ Please edit your previous question about this topic instead of asking new questions.

Answer (score 2):

If the table is created with 4 columns the `CREATE TABLE if not exist` will NOT add the extra column , in order to add a column you have to say `ALTER TABLE producttable ADD productadd TEXT`.

Comment: @mah I hope you are happy with this answer

Comment: It's not about me being happy with it :) I was simply telling you my opinion of your previous posting and why I voted it as I did. That being said, I agree that this posting is likely to satisfy the original question.

Comment: You are right but with less than 50 reputation you can't post comments. Thanks for the advice. :)